# Create alias type from object type property

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am facing the following problem with [Flow](https://flowtype.org/):

I have a type alias of an object, `A`:

```
type A = {
  B: {
    C: string
  }
}
```

I want to create another type alias, `B` p.e., that have the signature of the `B` property in `A`.

I tried with `type B = A.B;` but it Flow throws the following error:

```
[flow] [flow] B (Property cannot be accessed on type `A`)
```

I found a solution but it's a bit tricky and not elegant at all:

```
type A = {
  B: {
    C: string
  }
}

//FAKE constant of type A
const fakeA : A = (null : any);

type B = typeof fakeA.B;
```

Any other solution?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide some extra context - what language is this?  Also, when you say "it doesn't work" do you get any errors, or how does it not work?

Comment: Also, "flow" is a meta tag, generally not to be used.  There should be a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: I am using Javascript (ES6) with Flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$PropertyType` helper

```
type A = {
  B: {
    C: string
  }
}

type B = $PropertyType<A, 'B'>
```

See https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype for the full docs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this?

```
type B = {
  C: string
}
type A = {
  B: B
}
```

It's not exactly what you asked for, but it does allow you to avoid duplication. I don't believe there is a way to do exactly what you have asked for.

Comment: It's not exactly what I am looking for. I am currently using this approach. Thanks for the answer.